# Error after adding Laravel/Cashier

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-cashier

I got an error while trying to run composer update after adding laravel/cashier in my composer.json file.

Below is the screenshot of the error. Don't seem to understand what the error is.

Please, what I'm I missing here?

[image: error I got after adding laravel/cashier in my composer.json file]

[image: error aftre running composer update -vvv]

And my composer.json file is here below

```
{
"name": "lufficc/xblog",
"description": "A powerful and responsive blog system powered by laravel.",
"keywords": ["blog", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "erusev/parsedown": "^1.6",
    "qiniu/php-sdk": "^7.0",
    "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",
    "mews/purifier": "^2.0",
    "league/html-to-markdown": "^4.3",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "laravel/cashier": "~7.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"

},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "files":[
      "app/Helpers/helpers.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Lufficc\\": "app/Lufficc/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

It is now resolved by adding below code to my composer.json file

```
"repositories": [
{
     "type": "composer",
     "url": "https://packagist.org"
},
{ "packagist": false }
]
```

Comment: It looks like you just had a little trouble connecting to packagist; try running composer update again. You can also try running `composer clear-cache` to see if that works

Comment: I have actually run "composer clear-cache" still same issue

Comment: what laravel version are you using? The package could not be downloaded, maybe some older versions are used?

Comment: Can you also try doing it with `composer update -vvv` (adds debug output) and editing your question to include the input from that?

Comment: @kendepelchin I'm using 5.4

Comment: And finally, what does your composer.json file look like?

Comment: are you sure, that your internet connection is stable? the file https://packagist.org/p/league/oauth1-client%24059865b30afdc82ac82212c2cdfc1f155a0e4e71c3a286869b3965cb1ef40e11.json is correct. can you try wget'ing or curl'ing this url from the same machine were you run composer?

Comment: Finally found the solution.

Comment: @JustinChinonsoObi what was the problem?

Comment: Don't really know @kendepelchin Just added the few lines of code above in my composer.json file as directed by an article I saw on a website.